# Sensitivity and specificity with multiple sequential tests

Tags: false-discovery-rate, false-positive-rate

This has been on my mind for a while, and I would appreciate a statistician's view on the matter. Suppose that a given test has sensitivity $a$ and specificity $b$. Now, periodically apply this test over the same population multiple times. How do both values change under repeated tests in general?

Comment: There's a pretty interesting paper on the topic here: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3651832/